# how to set button alpha with an animation inside a for loop?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, animation, uibutton

i'm trying to set the button alpha in an animation.
i have tre button, one of this must be disappear during the animation, and the other 2 must be appear on the view.

this is my code:

```
    for (UIButton *button in self.buttonInView) {
        if ([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:TITLE_OF_START_BUTTON]) {

            [UIView animateWithDuration:10 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews animations:^{
                button.alpha = 0.00;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                button.hidden = NO;
            }];
        } else {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:10 delay:0.1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews animations:^{
                button.hidden = YES;
                button.alpha = 0.90;
            } completion:nil];
        }
    }
```

this code actually perform only the animation on the if statement, but no the other tow in the else statement.

how can i solve this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed it up where you set  the hidden property. Try this:

```
for (UIButton *button in self.buttonInView) {
    if ([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:TITLE_OF_START_BUTTON]) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:10 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews animations:^{
            button.alpha = 0.00;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            button.hidden = YES;
        }];
    } else {
        button.alpha = 0;
        button.hidden = NO;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:10 delay:0.1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews animations:^{
            button.alpha = 0.90;
        } completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: works! sorry for the stupid mistake, i have spent almost one hour to solve this! Thank you!